# Как запитать малинку от аккумулятора на 5в, если есть только + и -

Tags: raspberry-pi

Как запитать малинку от аккумулятора на 5в, если есть только + и -? Есть ли способы не через микро usb. Или как подключить микро usb провод к аккумулятору, чтоб малинка смогла питаться от него?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к тематики SO на русском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://kvvhost.ru/2019/05/29/zigbee2mqtt-cc2531-raspberry-pi/
В самом начале статьи есть цоколевка GPIO коннектора, там, где указан 5В и gnd - можно подключать 5 Вольт